# Date/time formats for various countries

Tags: locale

Is there any source on the web where I could find date and time formats used in individual countries in the World? I was checking languages listed in Control panel in Windows, but there are some countries missing (for example countries in Africa etc.).

I found some locale tables on the web, but these usualy differ from settings in Windows, so I don't know which version to use.

Thank you,
Petr

Answer (score 6):

The [Common Locale Data Repository](http://unicode.org/cldr/) is an excellent resource for locale data.  From the website you can download an xml version of the database, which includes datetime formats, number formats, and lots of other locale specific data.

Comment: Expand on this answer, and the acronym - Common Locale Data Repository; the people asking won't know what it is.  You'll get better marks with a more loquacious answer.

Answer (score 1):

This webpage shows how to use date and time based on culture settings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx

I'm assuming you're programming something so this would probably help you create a date-time based on the environmental settings.

As for using Windows settings vs researched settings, go with Windows settings if you're making something for Windows.

Comment: +1 for using Windows settings rather than your own settings when coding for Windows. Coding for the Web might involve a little more coding and configuration to allow for the same effect, but is still possible (and very nice when implemented correctly).

Comment: This link no longer works.  Do you have a reference to the new version?

Answer (score 1):

[This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#dd.2Fmm.2Fyyyy_or_dd.mm.yyyy_.28day.2C_month.2C_year.29) is the most comprehensive I've found, but it suffers from much the same problem you noted in Control Panel.  Maybe you can help by updating it with any information you've found independently?